# Conforming to a Swift Protocol - 'Value of type XX has no member YY'

Tags: swift

I have defined a protocol like so:

```
protocol Coordinator: NSObjectProtocol {
    var configurationStyle: ContainerConfigurationStyle { get }
}
```

Now, I am attempting to implement this like so:

```
class StoreCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    required init(withObject object: MyObject, style: ContainerConfigurationStyle) {
          self.object = object
          self.configurationStyle = style
}
```

This is giving me a compiler error saying 'StoreCoordinator does has no member configurationStyle. Why is this?

How can I enforce that my object has a configurationStyle property by using  a swift protocol?

Comment: Have you implemented the `configurationStyle` property in your `StoreCoordinator` class?

Comment: that is what I am attempting to do when i do this: `self.configurationStyle = style`

Comment: ah I guess you still have to declare it in the implementor's class

Comment: `class StoreCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    let object: MyObject;
    let configurationStyle: ContainerConfigurationStyle;
    required init(withObject object: MyObject, style: ContainerConfigurationStyle) {
        self.object = object
        self.configurationStyle = style
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I enforce that my object has a configurationStyle property by using a swift protocol?

A protocol is merely a list of requirements. To adopt the protocol you must obey its formal requirements.

Your protocol says "To adopt me, a type must declare a `var configurationStyle: ContainerConfigurationStyle`." You are not doing that. You would do it like this:

```
class StoreCoordinator: NSObject, Coordinator {
    var configurationStyle: ContainerConfigurationStyle 
    // ... and so on
}
```

A protocol does not have magic "injection" powers. Perhaps you are thinking of an extension? You can use a protocol extension, but be warned that then your property will not be visible to Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have now, there's no need for a protocol. Instead, just make `configurationStyle` a property of your `StoreCoordinator` class.

```
class StoreCoordinator: NSObject {
    var configurationStyle: ContainerConfigurationStyle!
    required init(withObject object: MyObject, style: ContainerConfigurationStyle) {
          self.object = object
          self.configurationStyle = style
}
```